# Delayed Jobs failing in production on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

**All** my delayed jobs are failing for no apparent reason in production on the server. I tried restarting, removing all previous jobs and again starting the job worker, but nothing worked.

Suspecting it must be a capistrano issue, I manually ran `rake jobs:work` via ssh on the server but I got the same error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-0:~/apps/instano-api/current$ rake jobs:work
[Worker(host:ip-172-31-35-0 pid:22174)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:ip-172-31-35-0 pid:22174)] Job InstanoMailer.new_quote (id=73) RUNNING
[Worker(host:ip-172-31-35-0 pid:22174)] Job InstanoMailer.new_quote (id=73) FAILED (3 prior attempts) with NameError: undefined method `error' for class `Class'
```

I use `ExceptionNotifier` gem, from which I got the following stack trace (but none of the lines are from my application code):

```
A NameError occurred in background at 2014-12-17 02:43:21 +0530 :

  undefined method `error' for class `Class'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:7:in `method'

  -------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:7:in `method'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:7:in `method'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:113:in `hook'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:97:in `rescue in block in invoke_job'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:101:in `block in invoke_job'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:82:in `block in timeout'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:70:in `catch'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:70:in `timeout'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:199:in `block in run'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:198:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:275:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:275:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:182:in `block in work_off'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `times'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `work_off'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:146:in `block (4 levels) in start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:145:in `block (3 levels) in start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:144:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:143:in `loop'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:143:in `block in start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:142:in `start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:124:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:112:in `block in run_process'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `block in start_proc'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call_as_daemon'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259:in `start_proc'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `block in run_proc'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:110:in `run_process'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:91:in `block in daemonize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `times'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `daemonize'
  bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'

-------------------------------
Data:
-------------------------------

  * data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a feature limitation in `Delayed Job`. Errors are not reported properly. The trace and error message is completely incorrect.

I debugged mine by looking at the rails production log. It was hard to find because there was no error while adding the task to delayed job i.e. I was getting a `[INFO]` tag instead of `[ERROR]` in logs.

I hope someone points out how to get proper and meaningful stack traces in case of failed Delayed Jobs.

*As a footnote,* my error was a real specific *(and lame)* one. My smtp settings in `/config/environments/production.rb` was incompatible my mailer so I was getting this error only in production.